# ionic 3 Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView

Tags: xcode, api, ionic-framework, uiwebview, deprecated

I am using ionic 3 ,trying to upload a build with xcode to apple appstore connect but i always keep getting this mail from apple , i tried many solutions and fixes but nothing actually happened .
any help please , thanks☺️ .

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "مفسر أحلامي" 1.0.0 (1.0.3). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Best regards,

The App Store Team

Comment: What Cordova version are you using? Also update your IOS platform.

`ionic cordova platform rm ios` and `ionic cordova platform add ios@latest`

Comment: Cordova version 9

Comment: `ionic cordova platform ls` also tell me output of this command.

Comment: Installed platforms:
  android 7.1.4
  browser 6.0.0
  ios 5.1.1
Available platforms: 
  electron ^1.0.0
  osx ^5.0.0
  windows ^7.0.0

Comment: Any help please!!

Comment: Update your cordova Versions and Plugins you are using..

Comment: all my plugins is up to date but also getting this ios build error with the file transfer plugin and it also up to date

Comment: The following build commands failed: CompileC /Users/moesaif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/مفسر_أحلامي-epzhtxsuxnuafngaxollgqmkcrww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/مفسر\ أحلامي.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/مفسر\ أحلامي.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o /Users/moesaif/Desktop/Dreams/platforms/ios/مفسر\ أحلامي/Plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/CDVFileTransfer.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler